# Distance between different points

Tags: coordinate-system, r, distance, coordinates, linestring

I am looking for a way to calculate the distance between different points in a linestring. 
In practice I created a linestring from a X and Y coordinate by means of

```
st_linestring(asNumericMatrix(dataset[dataset$Individual==1, 5:6])
```

I achieved to get the angle between different points with

```
PolygonAngles(st_linestring(asNumericMatrix(dataset[dataset$Individual==1, 5:6]))
```

Now I am looking for similar way to calculate the distance between different points.

Any suggestion?

Comment: A little editing would improve this question greatly. 1: I can't find a `PolygonAngles` or a `asNumericMatrix` in R, so if they are coming from a package please show the `library` call that gets those functions. 2: Try and make an example with data we can all use - eg see `help(st_linestring)` for examples of how to make linestrings from scratch. 3: make sure your code runs - there seems to be a mismatch of brackets. If you can edit the Q and do this then I think the answer is going to be some application of `st_distance`...